# only one return() for the entire method

Tags: c#

How can i have one return() for the entire codeblock instead of having a return in each if block. 
   Can somebody show me the better way writing the following block of code.

```
 public object GetHeaderInfo(string agentId, string headerName) 
 {
     if (headerName == "flyer")
     {
        var headerInfo = Service.GetFlierHeaderInfo(agentId);
        // headerinfo is of type Flier object
        return headerInfo;
     }
     if (headerName == "general")
     {
         var headerInfo = Service.GetHeaderInfo(agentId);
         // headerinfo is of type report object
         return headerInfo;
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: First of all indent your code. Then ask yourself why you are so keen to have a single `return`. The code is better with multiple returns.

Comment: a switch with multiple returns would be also clear...

Comment: I like this code. It is better than a single return :)

Comment: Dijkstra strikes again. Single entry-single exit methodology doesn't really apply to C# IMO.

Comment: Also note that this method almost certainly shouldn't be returning `object`.  Odds are good that there is a better type that you should be returning that actually has information about these header infos.  If the return values aren't identical then they should all implement a common interface.

Comment: @spender - I've never been able to understand why people are so eager to sacrifice the cleanliness and readability of code just to follow the "single-exit" rule. Not only in C#, but in most languages early returns make the code easier to understand in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a switch ?

```
switch (headerName) {
   case "flyer" : return Service.GetFlierHeaderInfo(agentId);
   case "general" : return  Service.GetHeaderInfo(agentId);
   default: return 0;
}
```

with only one return (which is less readable, but that's only a point of view).

```
object headerInfo = 0;

switch(headerName) {
     case "flyer" : headerInfo = Service.GetFlierHeaderInfo(agentId);
     break;
     case "general" : headerInfo = Service.GetHeaderInfo(agentId);
     break;
}
return headerInfo;
```

Comment: This is still multiple returns.

Comment: +1 for switch - `var` in original version did not match explicit comments in OP's sample code.

Answer (score 7):

The simple way to answer your question is:

```
object result = 0;
if (headerName == "flyer")
    result = Service.GetFlierHeaderInfo(agentId);
else if (headerName == "general")
    result = Service.GetHeaderInfo(agentId);
return result;
```

Or perhaps:

```
object result;
if (headerName == "flyer")
    result = Service.GetFlierHeaderInfo(agentId);
else if (headerName == "general")
    result = Service.GetHeaderInfo(agentId);
else
    result = 0;
return result;
```

---

That said, I think your code is better than that above. Multiple return statements is in fact exactly what you want for this function. This is a function that does not mutate state and has the sole task of returning a value. As soon as you know which value must be returned, do just that, return it.

I'd write it like this.

```
if (headerName == "flyer")
    return Service.GetFlierHeaderInfo(agentId);
if (headerName == "general")
    return Service.GetHeaderInfo(agentId);
return 0;
```

In my opinion this is easier to understand than the single return statement version.

---

I also question your choice of `0` as the fall-through value. Would it not make more sense to return `null` for that case? And is `object` really the correct type for the return value? Do you not have a common base class which you can use?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
Declare the `headerInfo` at the top with default value that you want to return in case of when no condition matched and then just set this variable inside your conditions and at last return it from function.

```
public object GetHeaderInfo(string agentId, string headerName) //(string Mlsnums)
{
  object headerInfo = 0;
  if (headerName == "flyer")
  {
      headerInfo = Service.GetFlierHeaderInfo(agentId);
  }
  else if (headerName == "general")
  {
     headerInfo = Service.GetHeaderInfo(agentId);
  }
  return headerInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare it at the top of your method :

```
public object GetHeaderInfo(string agentId, string headerName)
{
    object headerInfo = 0;

    if (headerName == "flyer")
    {
        headerInfo = Service.GetFlierHeaderInfo(agentId);
    }
    if (headerName == "general")
    {
        headerInfo = Service.GetHeaderInfo(agentId);
    }

    return headerInfo;
}
```

The default value can be added during the initialization, it will be overwritten by any future assignation.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public object GetHeaderInfo(string agentId, string headerName) //(string Mlsnums)
 {
     object headerinfo;

     if (headerName == "flyer")
     {
         headerInfo = Service.GetFlierHeaderInfo(agentId);
         // headerinfo is of type Flier object
     }
     if (headerName == "general")
     {
         headerInfo = Service.GetHeaderInfo(agentId);
         // headerinfo is of type report object
     }
         return headerInfo ?? 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public object GetHeaderInfo(string agentId, string headerName) //(string Mlsnums)
{
   switch (headerName )
   {
    case "flyer":
    return Service.GetFlierHeaderInfo(agentId);

    case "general":
    return Service.GetHeaderInfo(agentId);

    default:
    return 0;
  }
}
```

EDIT: I just now noticed that you wanted one return...

```
public object GetHeaderInfo(string agentId, string headerName) //(string Mlsnums)
{
   var headerInfo = 0;
   switch (headerName )
   {
    case "flyer":
    headerInfo = Service.GetFlierHeaderInfo(agentId);

    case "general":
    headerInfo  = Service.GetHeaderInfo(agentId);
   }
 return headerInfo ;
}
```

P.S: You can use it like this

```
public object GetHeaderInfo(string agentId, string headerName) //(string Mlsnums)
{
   return (headerName=="flyer"?Service.GetFlierHeaderInfo(agentId):headerName=="general"?Service.GetHeaderInfo(agentId):0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider...

```
public object GetHeaderInfo(string agentId, string headerName)
{
    object headerInfo = null;
    if (headerName == "flyer")
    {
        headerInfo = Service.GetFlierHeaderInfo(agentId);
    }
    if (headerName == "general")
    {
        headerInfo = Service.GetHeaderInfo(agentId);
    }
    return headerInfo;
}
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public object GetHeaderInfo(string agentId, string headerName) 
{
  object instance ;

  switch ( headerName )
  {
  case "flyer"   : instance = Service.GetFlierHeaderInfo( agentId ) ; break ;
  case "general" : instance = Service.GetHeaderInfo(      agentId ) ; break ;

  default        : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("headerName" ) ;
  }

  return instance ;
}
```